# Python msilib for mac

Tags: python, windows, macos, python-import

I'm trying to run a python script that has the following import statement:

```
from ast import keyword
from email.policy import default
from msilib.schema import ComboBox
from statistics import variance
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Variable, ttk
from turtle import onclick, width
```

I get an error on From msilib.schema import Combobox. I'm using a Mac and I see the lib is Microsofts, is there a way I can import a package so that I can use msilib on my Machine.

EDIT: The work around for anyone having the same issue is to run a virtual box with windows. It would still be nice to know how to run it on MAC but oh well...